# SuperSU not installing on HTC One S

Tags: rooting, htc, htc-one, supersu, htc-one-s

I am trying to root my HTC One S. The bootloader is `*** UNLOCKED ***`, TWRP is installed, and it's S-ON.

From [these instructions](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu/stable-2016-09-01supersu-v2-78-release-t3452703):

- I downloaded `SuperSU-v2.82-201705271822.zip` from the `TWRP / FlashFire installable ZIP` link.
- I did `adb push SuperSU-v2.82-201705271822.zip /storage/sdcard0/foo`
- I booted into TWRP and installed the above zip. Apart from complaining that `/data` could not be mounted (EDIT: fixed this by turning off encryption), it claims to have worked.
- I wiped the cache and rebooted.

Nevertheless, if I `adb shell` and `su` I get `/sbin/sh: su: not found`.

There is a `/supersu/` directory which contains `su` and some other stuff, but I can't run `/supersu/su`: permission denied. The `find` command finds no other file on the device matching `/su$/`.

I also tried `flashboot boot superboot.img` to get Superboot, but if I do this, the device does not boot past the initial splash screen (the one saying "This build is for development purposes only...").

What went wrong?

Comment: The failure in mounting `/data` may signal that the phone is encrypted. As of now, you have a half-working SuperSU.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I ran `recovery --wipe_data --set_filesystem_encryption=off` and now the `/data` warnings go away, but `su` is still not installed.

Comment: Did you reflash the SuperSU .zip?

Comment: Yes. Wiped everything I could and reflashed that zip.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I also tried Superboot, see edits to question.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm clueless when it comes to HTCs. Better wait for someone more knowledgeable in this regard.